# UIKIT_EXTERN_CLASS and UIKIT_EXTERN, for what these 2 constants are?

Tags: objective-c

When i go to definition of classes in documentation, i always see these 2 things (UIKIT_EXTERN_CLASS and UIKIT_EXTERN) before the @interface, what these constants stand for and why Apple put it before their classes?

And one more thing, there is file UIKitDefines.h and it has all these definitions/constants.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define UIKIT_EXTERN        extern "C" __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
#else
#define UIKIT_EXTERN            extern __attribute__((visibility ("default")))
#endif

#define UIKIT_STATIC_INLINE static inline
#define UIKIT_EXTERN_CLASS  __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html) from Apple's developer documentation. In essence, it appears those macros allow you to control the visibility of certain symbols to the rest of your application.

Comment: Aha, the very last sentence sums it up: "if a given class is intended to be usable outside the library or executable it's defined in, you need to ensure proper symbol visibility." [that's for 64bit OS X and iPhone OS]

Comment: The page referenced is now at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/CppRuntimeEnv/Articles/SymbolVisibility.html) as Apple seem intent on breaking any old links.