# When to use FOUNDATION_EXPORT?

Tags: objective-c

I am a bit confused as when we should use FOUNDATION_EXPORT in objective-c and what the purpose of that is? Can anyone explain in layman terms? Thanks!

Comment: See these two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953221/foundation-export-vs-extern, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c

Comment: also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668018/when-to-use-uikit-extern-vs-just-extern/17669269#17669269

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10953221/1698467

Answer (score 4):

> When we should use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` in Objective-c

Whenever you are importing foundation framework in Objective-C. It is the best practice to use `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` instead of `extern`. Because NSObjCRuntime.h in Foundation framework it includes c and c++ library. So for default visibility of the c and c++ symbols it compiles accordingly for making it more compatible.

Purpose of using FOUNDATION_EXPORT instead of extern:

1) Visible Symbolity

2) Compatibility to other source code.

Answer (score 2):

> When to use FOUNDATION_EXPORT?

Never.

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT` is an **undocumented** implementation detail of Apple's system frameworks so you should not use it at all.

Comment: What does means "**undocumented**"? Look in `NSObjCRuntime.h` + more detailed answer about here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10953284/1698467

Comment: I see Matt Thomson (AFNetworking creator) uses that in his libraries. Should we still not use it at all in 2017? Thanks!