# VersionNumber and VersionString in umbrella header

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a new framework to a Swift + Objective-C project.
So, into my framework, I have an umbrella header: `xFramework.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

//! Project version number for xFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double xFrameworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for xFramework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char xFrameworkVersionString[];
```

I don't want to depend upon `UIKit` in my framework. But, if I remove the import, `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` will not be found.

1. How much from this autogenerated file do I really need?
2. Are the `xFrameworkVersionNumber` and `xFrameworkVersionString[]` needed to be used in a Swift Framework?

I've understood from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192432/when-to-use-foundation-export) that `FOUNDATION_EXPORT` is a kind of `public`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

by

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```